# how to add a textfield by pressing a button

Tags: ios, button, uiview, uitextfield, addition

I'm trying to figure out how to add a textfield in a view in my iphone app by clicking on a button. Is it possible?

I thought it should be as easy as this. But it's not working.

```
- (IBAction)addText:(id)sender

CGRect textField = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 100.0, 30.0);
UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:textField];
```

Comment: Of course it's possible! Making views come and go is the essence of iOS. Have you tried anything at all yet?

Comment: I altered my question and posted my attempt there

Comment: Post your real code. What you posted isn't even close to something that will compile.

Comment: BTW - please be a lot clearer than saying "it's not working". Never use those words when asking a question. Be specific. Does it compile? If not, what are the errors? If it compiles then what actually happens at runtime? Does it crash? If so, what is the error and at what line does it crash? If it doesn't crash, be clear about what happens compared to what should happen. It's these kind of details that make the difference between a bad question and a good question.

Comment: maddy, thanks for your input. I will keep that in mind next time i need help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi John yes you can create uitextfield after clicking the button for that you have to write code as such below

```
- (IBAction)addText:(id)sender
{
CGRect textfieldFrame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 100.0, 30.0);
UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:textfieldFrame];
textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
textField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
textField.placeholder = @"enter text";
textField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
textField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;    
textField.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:textField];



}
```

Comment: This looks like it should work but it's not. Is there something more to it than just this?

Comment: Hi john I edited my answer please use this code it will work defenetly.

Comment: Thanks!!! care to explain what the problem was so I could learn something out of this? :)

Comment: Hi John here problem is previously we used same object names for CGrect and UItextfield  due to that compiler is getting confused and showing errors. Now i change the CGrect object name as textfieldFrame instead of textField (Which we used earlier). This is only the main cause.

Answer (score 0):

If this code not work, mean your IBAction of UIButton not work put NSLog in IBAction or write UITextView global variable, because maybe it is super call dealloc your UITextView. Or maybe your CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 100.0, 30.0) frame out of your view exceed max with or max height and you not see its.

```
- (IBAction)addText:(id)sender {
     CGRect textFieldFrame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 100.0, 30.0);
     UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:textFieldFrame];   
     textField.delegate = self;
     [self.view addSubview:textField];
     // or add to you wanted view
    [yourView addSubview:textField];
}
```

Comment: not working, is there something else I should do to get this to work?